# Google Chart API - Pie legend.textStyle color

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, google-visualization

Starting from the [official example](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html) for pie chart.
I'm not able the change the legend color.

```
'legend.textStyle': { 'color': 'gray' }
```

Is not taken into account.
Please check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjHnT/)
Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wasn't actually able to get your answer to work either. Instead, I used the following:

```
legend: {textStyle: {color: 'gray'}}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is

```js
legend: {textStyle: {color: 'gray'}}
```

instead of

```
'legend.textStyle': { 'color': 'gray' }
```

Comment: Without the quotes, certain browsers don't allow quoted object keys

Comment: Because I left the keys quoted (it was working with my browsers) My answer is 5 month earlier than @Xaniff 's I was saying "works better" compared to my question

Comment: Yes, but your point is relevant, browser support can be important, and now the answer is the same. I have a fear it'll be downvoted.

Comment: Why don't you say `'legend': {'textStyle': { 'color': 'gray' }}`?